# SwiftUI Navigation Link embedded in a Button with an action

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I've made a Button view in my body and I have set it's action to a Google Sign In action, but I want it to also transition to a new view when the sign in flow is completed. The problem is that I have set the label of the button to a Navigation Link and when I click it, it directly transitions to a next view. How can I delay the transition? For context, VoucherView is the next view I want to transition to.

```
Button {
                    guard let clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID else { return }
                    
                    // Create Google Sign In configuration object.
                    let config = GIDConfiguration(clientID: clientID, serverClientID: GlobalConstants.BACKEND_SERVER_REQUEST_ID_TOKEN)
                    
                    guard let presenter = CommonHelper.GetRootViewController() else {return}
                    
                    // Start the sign in flow!
                    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: config, presenting: presenter) {user, error in
                        
                        if let error = error {
                            print (error.localizedDescription)
                            return
                        }
                        
                        guard
                            let authentication = user?.authentication,
                            let idToken = authentication.idToken
                        else {
                            print ("Something went wrong!")
                            return
                        }
                        
                        print (authentication)
                        print (idToken)
                        
                        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken,
                                                                       accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
                        print (credential)
                        UserManager.shared.firebaseAuthentication(credential: credential)
                        signed = true
                        
                    }
                } label: {
                    NavigationLink {
                        
                        VoucherView()
                        
                    } label: {
                        Text("Sign In")
                    }

                }
```

Edit: After I tried using isValid as a @State variable, after every cycle of SignIn and SignOut the screen goes down.

[First SignIn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCXs7.png)

[FirstSignOut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1fHt.png)

[SecondSignIn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3yyo.png)

[SecondSignOut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1jFX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `NavigationLink` *inside* your `Button`, you can use a `NavigationLink` with an `EmptyView` for a label and then activate it programmatically with the `isActive` parameter.

See the following example -- the Google Sign In process is replaced by just a simple async closure for brevity.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var navigateToNextView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                        navigateToNextView = true
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Sign in")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: View2(), isActive: $navigateToNextView) { EmptyView()
                }
            }
        }.navigationTitle("Test")
    }
}

struct View2 : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Next view")
    }
}
```

A couple more notes:

- Note that there has to be a `NavigationView` (make sure it's *just one*) in the hierarchy for this to work
- In general, async work is better done in an `ObservableObject` than in a `View`. You can consider moving your login function to an `ObservableObject` and making the `navigateToNextView` a `@Published` property on that object.

Comment: Your method worked pretty good, except there is a little problem. Every time I go back from the second to the first view and back, the second view moves down a little bit, which is a very strange behaviour.

Comment: I'm not seeing that with my code. Are you sure that you're testing *just* the code I presented with no modifications? It sounds like a symptom of having multiple `NavigationView`s in your hierarchy.

Comment: Yeah the code is one to one, there is only one NavigationView, there are two files and that's it.

Comment: What version of iOS?

Comment: iOS 15.0, can it be related?

Comment: Hard to say, since I can't reproduce it. Can you post screenshots as an edit to your question?

Comment: Screenshots of the problem only or the code too?

Comment: Don't need screenshots of the code -- you said you're just using my exact code. I'd need screenshots of the symptoms -- it's hard to know what "moves down a little bit" means.

Comment: Ok, I've posted them.

Comment: That absolutely looks like two `NavigationView`s. If you search your Xcode project for `NavigationView`, how many results come up? Or, alternately, one `NavigationView` that gets pushed to the stack multiple times.

Comment: When I search it, it comes up only once, how can it be pushed multiple times?

Comment: Does the “sign out” link have a destination where the NavigationView is included? Meaning ContentView -> LoggedInView -> ContentView again? My code didn’t include a “sign out link”, so that’s my guess. If so, you have to have a parent view that does not get pushed again (eg put the NavigationView one level higher). Plus, pushing a *new* view when logging out probably isn’t what you want long term. You probably want to pop back to the root view.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I really want, but the problem is I don't know how can I pop back to the root view without pushing a new view and you are absolutely right, I'm calling the view which has the NavigationView in it.

Comment: I had a feeling that the code you were using wasn’t exactly mine :) Search SwiftUI pop to root to find solutions. It’ll involve storing that isActive variable somewhere you can reference it from the child and then setting it to false.

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time with my stupidity, I will search more into the topic.